# How to fix "Element type is invalid: expected a string ... but got: object" error in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working in a React.js front end with a Node.js back end and I'm trying to create an app that allows a user to upload an image and then display that image in a gallery on the user's home page. The problem I'm getting is an error in the gallery component that says, "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object" and I can't seem to find where it's coming from, nor do I really understand what it means.

I've tried commenting out different pieces of code, but the error remains the same.

The current component on the front end gallery is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import ReactGallery from 'react-photo-gallery';
import Lightbox from 'react-images';
import { loadAuthToken } from "../local-storage";

export default class Gallery extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            images : [],
            currentImage: 0,
            lightboxIsOpen: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("auth");
        axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:8080/api/images/",
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${loadAuthToken()}` }
        }).then(response => {
          this.setState({
            images: response.data
          });
        });
      }

    openLightbox(event, obj) {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: obj.index,
            lightboxIsOpen: true,
        });
    }
    closeLightbox() {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: 0,
            lightboxIsOpen: false,
        });
    }
    gotoPrevious() {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: this.state.currentImage - 1,
        });
    }
    gotoNext() {
        this.setState({
            currentImage: this.state.currentImage + 1,
        });
    }

    render() {
        let photos = this.state.images.map(image => {
            return {
                src : '/api/images' + image.uri,
                width : image.width,
                height : image.height,
                id :  image.id
            }
        });
        if (!this.state.images.length) return null; 
        return (
            <div className="gallery">
                {this.state.images.length ?
                    <ReactGallery
                        photos={photos}
                        onClick={this.openLightbox.bind(this)}
                    />
                    :
                    <div className="no-images">
                        <h5 className="text-center">
                            You currently have no images in your photos gallery
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                }

                <Lightbox images={photos}
                          onClose={this.closeLightbox.bind(this)}
                          onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious.bind(this)}
                          onClickNext={this.gotoNext.bind(this)}
                          currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
                          isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

The full front end is here: https://github.com/beccaww/cats-client

The back end is here: https://github.com/beccaww/cats

I expect there to be a gallery of images that the user uploads, not the error message. Is there anyone who can shed some light on the error and what it might mean?

Comment: Could you mention the line number of the error?

Comment: can you comment out the imports (and the related elements) of `react-photo-gallery` and `react-images`?  and enable only 1 at a time.. if you find which one is problematic, check the version of the library is compatible with the version of React.

Comment: The error is on line 24.

Comment: Commenting out ```react-photo-gallery``` gives a "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" and commenting out ```react-images``` doesn't change the "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object" error. Would that mean I should look at the ```react-photo-galley```?

Answer (score 1):

at line 24: you are using response.data which gives you the json object and you have set images state to take array. 
to solve console.log(response.data) and check the json object value you want and then update your images state.

```
axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:8080/api/images/",
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${loadAuthToken()}` }
     }).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
     });
```